# Python: parallel loop

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

I have dataframe and column

```
event_time
avito.ru/morozovsk/avtomobili/honda_accord_1998_799656153
avito.ru/donetck/avtomobili/honda_accord_2000_829068734
avito.ru/taganrog/avtomobili/volkswagen_passat_1997_839237476
avito.ru/volgodonsk/avtomobili/volkswagen_golf_1993_657720225
avito.ru/taganrog/avtomobili/peugeot_206_2008_818743294
avito.ru/bataysk/avtomobili/peugeot_206_2002_825498743
```

and I need to open html page. I use proxy and use code

```
for url in urls:
m = re.search(r'avito.ru\/[a-z]+\/avtomobili\/[a-z0-9_]+$', url)
if m is not None:
    url = 'https://www.' + url
    proxy = pd.read_excel('proxies.xlsx')
    proxies = proxy.proxy.values.tolist()
    for i, proxy in enumerate(proxies):
        # print "Trying HTTP proxy %s" % proxy
        try:
            result = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies={'http': proxy}).read()
            if 'Мы обнаружили, что запросы, поступающие с вашего IP-адреса, похожи на автоматические' in result:
                raise Exception
            else:
                page = page.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
                price = soup.find('span', itemprop="price")
                print price
        except:
            print "Trying next proxy %s in 30 seconds" % proxy
            time.sleep(30)
```

But it need a lot of time! I want to do it faster.
I try to add this code to func

```
def get_page(url):
```

and next

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(get_page, urls)
```

I want to open some url with some proxy, but it works wrong for me.

Is any way to solve my task?

Comment: "it works wrong for me" What's wrong with it. Details...

Comment: @MooingRawr it gets 8 urls and try to open that with one proxy. But I want to open one url with some proxy and at the same time open others urls with others proxies